# How to Fix "Missing platform binary:" nexus-2.11.2-03?

Tags: maven, raspberry-pi, nexus, raspbian

I was going to setup my **local nexus repository** on **Raspberry Pi B+**, **Raspbian** OS.
but when i tried to start-up Nexus OSS then i got an error

`"Missing platform binary:" /home/pi/Desktop/nexus-2.11.2-03/bin/. ./bin/jsw/linux-armv6l-32/wrapper`

**Found [some information](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6173) that:**

> The generic bin/nexus script does not work properly on non-standard
>   Linux distributions.

but doesn't solve my problem

Is there any way i can start-up Nexus on Raspberry Pi Raspbian OS?

Thanks

Comment: The JSW is intended to start Nexus as a service but of course you can start Nexus as simple java app...instead...But i would like to know why you like to start a Nexus on a Respberry ?

Comment: *Raspberry, i just want to make it as my local maven repository,  just trying to make a use of it [Raspberry] that i was about to throw away.

Comment: Have you tried to use `nexus console`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here on Red Hat and could solve it by making the wrapper executable.

```
chmod u+x wrapper
```

Comment: I copy the folder nexus to another server,then nexus start met the issue,then I am also use the command "chmod u+x wrapper" fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

On Red Hat 6.x, I ended having to ignore the documentation and make a link to the start script instead of copying as the documentation states.

```
ln -s /opt/nexus/bin/nexus /etc/init.d/nexus
```

So something similar might work for Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

Exist an alternative wrapper for Linux ARM systems at http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp.
Download the community version of Linux armel, create a linux-armv6l-32 directory under jsw, and copy the wrapper file that inside the tar file in the bin folder. It works for me.

Comment: Looks like this should work, however, readers should be advised that the tanukisoftware wrapper is a time limited wrapper. The initial licence allows execution for 15mins only. Trial 1 month licences are available on request, anything more than that requires a purchase.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for pre 3.0 nexus is available [here](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6173). It simply involves editing the startup script. 
Replace:

```
DIST_ARCH=`uname -p | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] | tr -d [:blank:]`
```

With:

```
DIST_ARCH=`uname -m | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] | tr -d [:blank:]`
```

Comment: This doesn't work on RPI (which OP is clearly using). `uname -m` returns 'armvl6' and so starting nexus still attempts to load the missing library.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error, the startup script was not able locate the wrapper file.
The reason was that I declare the NEXUS_HOME to '/usr/local/nexus' in bin/nexus file as per a tutorial. Setting the nexus installation directory as NEXUS_HOME resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the NEXUS_HOME to a path above the bin directory to avoid the error of missing binay